# Is returning inside a 'with' statement dangerous?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I need to return the contents of a file, is it fine to do this :

```py
def foo(filePath):
    with open(filePath) as f:
        return json.load(f)
```

Or should I do this instead :

```py
def foo(filePath):
    with open(filePath) as f:
        r = json.load(f)
    return r
```

(*Of course my functions do other stuff, this is a toy model*)

Comment: @CeliusStingher we don't know without more clarification from OP, but that thread is perhaps one part of the question. I assumed OP was asking broadly, i.e. are there any other issues returning like that could cause? (I'd say it's too broad as-is)

Comment: @BruceWayne The duplicate thread answers the question, I just wanted to be sure ```return``` doesn't somehow break context managers, and it seems like it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning inside a `with` block is not dangerous. Write it the first way.

Comment: I assume that doing it the first way also closes `f` when it `return`s?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes, that's one of the main reasons for using a context manager - it takes care of all the cleanup for you.